# Qr code generation on the server in java gwt

Tags: java, qr-code

I need to develop web app that will return qr code(or link to qr code) to mobile clients. I plan to learn the basics of GWT because i alredy know java programming.
 Is it possible to use zxing libraries or some other java libraries with GWT, so generating (encoding) QR codes could be done with a few lines of code? Or do you suggest any other option?

The QR code that will be returned by server will depend on ID that will come with the request from mobile phone.

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating the QR code in-server using a library such as **zxing** is a pretty obvious way to go about this an could be absolutely appropriate for your application.

But you might also consider off-loading this to an external web-service such as [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). See [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/qr_codes.html). The advantage of this approach, if it works for you, is that you free your service resources and bandwidth from the responsibility so it would likely scale better and be less complex to develop.

The caveat is, of course, is that your application would have to satisfy the provider's terms of use

Comment: I downloaded  chart Tools API Library for GWT (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) but can't find qr code in their javadoc.
 Is this thing included in library for GWT?

Comment: The Google Chart API (of which the QR stuff is a subset) stands apart from GWT (Google's AJAX development framework for Java). I don't know what level of support the GWT binding have for QR codes. Are you wedded to going a GWT route?